# Set caret position to zero inside node of contenteditable element in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, selection, contenteditable

I have to create a simple text editor. To work in all browser is not required, if it work in latest firefox and chrome are enough.

So the problem is, i have a contenteditable div with child nodes and in chrome when i step inside a node its step automatically to after first letter. Is it possible to set the caret to the zero position?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tyjx5m0e/2/)

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  some <span>text</span> other text
</div>
```

When caret step inside the span in chrome, the caret automatically placed after t. I tired to set the position with selection and range, but it doesn't worked.

UPDATE: SOLVED, see my answer, to get how.

In firefox its work as i want.

Comment: Is that fiddle supposed to demonstrate the issue, because it behaves identically in chrome and firefox.

Comment: When i use firefox, the caret placed after '>' (span:before content). In chrome the caret placed after t letter inside span tag. This happen when i step by arrow keys and step inside the span element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, how tired to find a solution for this.

If the child eleme (sapn) has contenteditable attribute with true, its work.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  some <span contenteditable="true">text</span> other text
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tyjx5m0e/5/)